# Creating semaphore with initial value of 0 make issues with execution

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I'm learning GCD and got question about semaphore.
Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var semaphore: dispatch_semaphore_t! = nil

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0)) {
      print("Entering")

      self.semaphoreTask()
      print(self.semaphore.debugDescription)
    }

    semaphoreTask()
     print(semaphore.debugDescription)
  }


  func semaphoreTask() {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    for i in 0...1000 {
      print(i)
      if i == 1000 {
        print("i is equal to 10000!")
      }
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore)
  }
```

If I run this code so nothing from semaphoreTask is printed in the console, but if I change

```
semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
```

to

```
semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1)
```

Everything starts work well.

The question is why should I write dispatch_semaphore_create(1) but not 0?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the semaphore in 2 different ways:

1. To say when work or a resource is ready.
   In this case you start the semaphore at 0. The creator calls `signal` when something is ready. The consumer calls `wait` to wait for the expected item / resource.
2. To limit the number of concurrent operations / requests / usages.
   In this case you start the semaphore at a positive value, like 4. The users each call `wait` and if resource is available they are allowed to continue. If not they are blocked. When each has finished with the resource they call `signal`.

So, what you see it expected because you're setting the semaphore up as a ready flag but using it as an access limit (because you call `wait` first).

Comment: Thank you! I got the point. So If I put 0 it wants to execute something but then I say wait and it waits. That was my mistake. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

So I corrected my code to show you how I fixed it (thanks to @Wain).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var semaphore: dispatch_semaphore_t! = nil

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0)) {
      print("Entering")

      self.semaphoreTask()
    }


    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    semaphoreTask()
  }


  func semaphoreTask() {

    print(semaphore.debugDescription)
    for i in 0...1000 {
      print(i)
      if i == 1000 {
        print("i is equal to 10000!")
      }
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore)
  }
}
```

Comment: consider printing the thread that is running in `semaphoreTask` so you can see if it's main or the background thread and confirm that main waited for the background thread to complete